# Trouble with a Conditional Operator and IF...ELSE Statement

Tags: javascript, onclick, conditional-operator

Trying to get a default string of text to show after all subsections are closed using the following Conditional Operator inside an onclick event. I have 3 other Conditional Operators in the event and they all work fine.  This is the only one with a Logical Operator in it.  Everything else after this line is never rendered.

```
document.getElementById('itemMain1').className=(document.getElementById('subItem1A').className=='hidden' && document.getElementById('subItem1B').className=='hidden')?'block':'hidden'
```

I have also tried it with an IF Statement.

```
if (document.getElementById('subItem1A1').className=='hidden' 
   && document.getElementById('subItem1B').className=='hidden')
{
    document.getElementById('itemMain1').className='block';
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('itemMain1').className='hidden';
}
```

Would love to know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: What's the error that you're getting? Are you sure those element IDs exist?

Comment: Agree with @judgeja that Which type of errors you're receiving?

Comment: Not getting error messages.  Everything after the line as well as the DIV it is in just does not show up on the page.  I took elements out until it worked again.  This was the only one that stopped everything from working.

The only difference between this and the other lines of code are that it checks IDs that it is not changing and there is an && to make sure both elements are hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to realy easy and just a slight variation on the code used to make the sub headings text visable and is as follows.

> document.getElementById('itemMain1').className=(document.getElementById('subItem1A').className!='block')?'block':'hidden'

This goes in the onclick for subItem1A and again for each subItem1, changing the subItem1 reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve... 'hidden' is for visibility.

```
document.getElementById('itemMain1').style.display=(document.getElementById('subItem1A').style.display=='none' && document.getElementById('subItem1B').style.display=='none')?'block':'none';
```

Tell me if this works. I will tell you more about it.

Comment: I am hiding <div>s of text with a css class. Then I am using an onclick to change the class to a none hidden class while hiding other <div>s that where showing.  What I need is for the oncick to realize that all the <div>s are hidden and to apply the non hidden css class to the default <div>